# Как отправить эмодзи через бота в телеграмме?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Хочу на сообщение пользователя отправить в ответ сообщением со смайликом, но не понимаю как это сделать. Видел что-то про юникод, но что-то не разобрался

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: «Видел что-то про юникод, но что-то не разобрался» ну так разберитесь. Вот тут интересно https://habr.com/ru/company/itelma/blog/549366/

Comment: Копируете смайлик (emoji), вставляете его прямо в строку, эту строку отправляете как сообщение.

Answer (score 1):

Я обычно беру [отсюда](https://unicode-table.com/ru/sets/emoji) юникодовские эмоджи. Можете либо копировать его напрямую через кнопку **Копировать**

[image: Копировать эмодзи]

Либо брать код символа и вставлять его в строку, для данного эмодзи это будет выглядеть вот так: `u"\U0001F680"`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]